# Can I use pthread mutex under GCD concurrency context

Tags: ios, concurrency, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

My function can be called concurrently by other‘s program using GCD. Can I lock resources by using pthread mutex?

Comment: “Can I lock resources by using pthread mutex?” ... You _can,_ but why would you? There  are better, more intuitive, mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. At the end of the day, code running under GCD is just code running on a regular, old OS thread that just *happens* to be managed by GCD. As @Daniel points out, if you're using GCD throughout, you ought to use GCD's mechanisms for mutual exclusion (i.e. a serial queue), but if you're interoperating with legacy code that uses pthread mutexes to lock resources, you can certainly do that from within code executed by GCD as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully (if you can attach code it will be very helpful),
I suggest reading this short post -[gcd-queues-synchronization](https://www.humancode.us/2014/08/02/gcd-queues-synchronization.html)
Maybe you can make sure that the function is running on the same queue (thread) using GCD and it will solve your synchronization problem.